# Best way to insert dataframe into stackoverflow question

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I’m regularly searching stackoverflow for pandas and Python wisdom. (Plenty here). But to better setup my pandas questions I’m left to manually inserting sample data in a sample dataframe illustrating my questions. Is there a video or step by step tutorial to most efficiently add a dataframe to a question?  If not, whomever responds with a step by step, I’ll make the screencast video and paste the link here.  (Pay it forward and such). Thanks.

Comment: This sort of question belongs on [meta] instead of here. Also, questions asking us to recommend or find an off-site resource (a video or tutorial) are off-topic according to the [help/on-topic] guidelines.

Comment: I have never heard of metastack overflow. Thanks for that. I’ll post it there.  As for off site links, I was reviewing a question just today which had links to outside resources (ones that were helpful to me!).  I didn’t realize those tires of things violated the rules. Thanks for that info too!

Comment: Your question has already been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples).

Comment: Actually, what I meant was not how to create sample dataframes (although the answers to that question were educational) but how to best paste said dataframes into a SO question.